# How to operate this query by putting mentioned condition?

Tags: sql, count, concatenation

My table is as follows

```
ID  Name
1   Amit
2   Shalu
2   Ram
3   John
3   Kripa
3   Manish
3   Abhi
1   Ayush
```

My requirement is to generate a query that will make the format as

```
ID  Name
1   Amit OR Ayush
2   Shalu OR Ram
3   John AND Kripa AND Manish AND Abhi
```

Conditions: when count(Id)=2 concatenate OR with Names
when count(Id)>3 concatenate AND with Name

I am trying to modify this query to acheive above requirement:

```
select id,
  REPLACE(stuff((select ',' + '  ' + name  + '  '
from @Table b
where b.id = a.id
  FOR xml path('')),1,1,' '),',','OR') MergedDatafrom @Table agroup by a.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a union approach:

```
<query that uses OR>
group by a.id
having count(*) <= 2

UNION ALL

<query that uses AND>
group by a.id
having count(*) > 2
```

Comment: Thanks dude it worked for me and i hope i will not face any other issues. Thanks alot